Do results of Prepared Statements differ depending on where it is initialized?
Is it expected that prepared statement queries will (or will not) take uncommitted changes into consideration when queried, depending on whether a statement is prepared within the same connection as a transaction?
For example:
// Open, prepare statement, close
sqlite3* db = nullptr;
sqlite3_open(filename, &db);
sqlite3_stmt* count_stmt = nullptr;
sqlite3_prepare_v3(db, "SELECT count(*) FROM names", -1, SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT, & count_stmt, nullptr));
sqlite3_close(db);
// Then open and start transaction and run prepared statement
sqlite3_open(filename, &db);
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", nullptr, nullptr, &err);
sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('John')", nullptr, nullptr, &err);
sqlite3_step(count_stmt);
int count = sqlite3_column_int(count_stmt, 0);
sqlite3_close(db);
REQUIRE(count == 1); // fails because transaction wasn't commited

But if I prepare the statement in the same connection that is used by the transaction, the results will take the transaction into consideration before committing.
// Open, prepare statement, begin transaction and query
sqlite3* db = nullptr;
sqlite3_open(filename, &db);
sqlite3_stmt* count_stmt = nullptr;
sqlite3_prepare_v3(db, "SELECT count(*) FROM names", -1, SQLITE_PREPARE_PERSISTENT, & count_stmt, nullptr));
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", nullptr, nullptr, &err);
sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('John')", nullptr, nullptr, &err);
sqlite3_step(count_stmt);
int count = sqlite3_column_int(count_stmt, 0);
sqlite3_close(db);
REQUIRE(count == 1); // passes even though transaction hasn't been committed yet


Related: Can statement prepared with sqlite3_prepare_v2 be used with a different connection?

A prepared statement is executed using the connection it was prepared in. If you start a transaction in a different connection, the prepared statement won't be executed in that transaction.

The first snippet is simply wrong. count_stmt can only be executed on the first connection, but you closed it before executing.

It might be wrong as in "bad" but not wrong as in "invalid".  The sqlite3_step(count_stmt); will return results and will count rows that existed in the table before the transaction was begun.

There is an error in your code: you are clearly using an sqlite prepared statement associated with a database connection after the database was closed!
This is also logically wrong!
But why it didn't cause crashes? Or why it seems to work?
From the sqlite3_close docs:

If the database connection is associated with unfinalized prepared
statements, BLOB handlers, and/or unfinished sqlite3_backup objects
then sqlite3_close() will leave the database connection open and
return SQLITE_BUSY. If sqlite3_close_v2() is called with unfinalized
prepared statements, unclosed BLOB handlers, and/or unfinished
sqlite3_backups, it returns SQLITE_OK regardless, but instead of
deallocating the database connection immediately, it marks the
database connection as an unusable "zombie" and makes arrangements to
automatically deallocate the database connection after all prepared
statements are finalized, all BLOB handles are closed, and all backups
have finished.

This means that when you closed the first connection before finalizing (closing) the prepared statement associated with it, the connection was not closed! It is still alive until the statement is closed, and when the statement is executed it is executed on the first connection, not the second!
Why this awkward behavior from sqlite? From the docs:

The sqlite3_close_v2() interface is intended for use with host
languages that are garbage collected, and where the order in which
destructors are called is arbitrary.

But why it fails in the first example and not in the second? Well, your application should be able to examine the results of executed statements of a transaction even before the transaction is committed, This is why the second example succeeds.
For the first example: the prepared statement and the transaction are associated with different connections, so either the behavior is undefined, or the prepared statement can't access the transaction result in the second connection.
Edit: inside a transaction on a connection, only this connection can see the results of this transaction before it is committed, and after commitment all other connections can see its results. This may explain why in the first example the prepared statement on the first connection is not seeing the result of the uncommitted transaction on the second connection.
Regardless, you must always close all the resources associated with the database connection before closing the connection itself. From the docs:

Ideally, applications should finalize all prepared statements, close
all BLOB handles, and finish all sqlite3_backup objects associated
with the sqlite3 object prior to attempting to close the object.


Thanks for the clear explanation.  I found this behavior while testing a change from a single long lasting connection with prepared statements to constructing the db and prepared statements once and opening/closing connections as needed.  I had just read that it was recommended but that seems counter to this here unless the cost to  prepare statements is negligible.
